# Runnig TestNG test with Bazel

Tags: java, testng, bazel, bazel-rules

I have a test project, it is configured with maven and TestNG, it works perfectly fine with it.
I want to use Bazel to run the same project. I have created WORKSPACE and BUILD files for each directory, which builds perfectly fine.
I want to run the test using the 'testng_regressions.xml' in this direcotry: src/test/resources/testrunners/testng_regressions.xml

This is the BUILD file for 'testng_regressions.xml',

```
load("@rules_java//java:defs.bzl", "java_test")

java_library(
    name = "main_project_files",
    srcs = glob(['src/main/java/**/*.java']),
    runtime_deps = [
        "//Web/src/main/java/io/package/com/constants:app_constants",
        "//Web/src/main/java/io/package/com/factory:playwright_factory",
        "//Web/src/main/java/io/package/com/listeners:extent_report_listener",
        "//Web/src/main/java/io/package/com/pages:login_page",
        "//Web/src/main/java/io/package/com/steps:login_steps",
    ],
)

java_library(
    name = "test_project_files",
    srcs = glob(['src/test/java/**/*.java']),
    runtime_deps = [":main_project_files",
            "//Web/src/test/java/io/package/com/base:base_test",
            "//Web/src/test/java/io/package/com/tests:project_test_files"],
)
#
java_test(
    name = "testng_regressions",
    size = "small",
    timeout = "short",
    tags = ["regression"],
    runtime_deps = [
        ":main_project_files",
        ":test_project_files"
    ],
    use_testrunner = False,
    main_class='org.testng.TestNG',
    args=['-testjar','libtest_project_files.jar','-verbose','2'],
)
```

This is the content of the testNG file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Open Cart Test Regression PW Suite" thread-count="5"
       parallel="tests" verbose="4">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="io.christdoes.com.listeners.ExtentReportListener" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="Open Cart Home Page Test_chrome">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <parameter name="language" value="en" />
        <classes>
            <class name="io.christdoes.com.tests.HomePageTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Open Cart Login Page Test_safari">
        <parameter name="browser" value="safari" />
        <parameter name="language" value="nl" />
        <classes>
            <class name="io.christdoes.com.tests.HomePageTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

When I run the test, it always give a non-detailed error

```
FAIL: //Web/src/test/resources/testrunners:testng_regressions (see /private/var/tmp/_bazel_christdoes/44565daf5d57f20e3e02fd7160ffadab/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/Web/src/test/resources/testrunners/testng_regressions/test.log)
INFO: Elapsed time: 91.557s, Critical Path: 31.65s
INFO: 17 processes: 3 internal, 6 darwin-sandbox, 8 worker.
INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 17 total actions
//Web/src/test/resources/testrunners:testng_regressions                  FAILED in 2.1s
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/44565daf5d57f20e3e02fd7160ffadab/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/Web/src/test/resources/testrunners/testng_regressions/test.log

Executed 1 out of 1 test: 1 fails locally.
```

How do I run the test using testNG?